# Reflection formula for the ${}_2\!F_1$ hypergeometric function of a matrix argument

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

According to my implementation of the hypergeometric function of a matrix argument, the so-called "Reflection formula" for ${}_2\!F_1$ given on [DMLF (formula 35.7.8)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/35.7) is not true.

On the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Fractional_linear_transformations) about ${}_2\!F_1$ in the scalar case, there is a formula identical to the one given on DMLF except that this one has an additional term (and I have checked that this formula is true):
[image]

So I have naively tried to generalize this formula to the matrix case as follows:
$$
{{}_{2}}\! F_1
\left(\begin{matrix} a, b \\ c\end{matrix}; 
T\right) 
= \frac{\Gamma_m(c)\Gamma_m(c-a-b)}{\Gamma_m(c-a)\Gamma_m(c-b)}
{{}_{2}}\! F_1
\left(\begin{matrix} a, b \\ a+b-c + \frac{m+1}{2}\end{matrix}; 
I - T\right) +
$$
$$
\qquad\frac{\Gamma_m(c)\Gamma_m(a+b-c)}{\Gamma_m(a)\Gamma_m(b)} 
\det(I-T)^{c-a-b}
{{}_{2}}\! F_1
\left(\begin{matrix} c-a, c-b \\ c-a-b + \frac{m+1}{2} \end{matrix}; 
I-T\right).
$$
Now, playing with my implementation, I observed that this equality seems to hold true *when $T$ is very close to the identity matrix $I$* (like $\textrm{diag}(0.97,0.98,0.99)$). But when I take another matrix $T$, even $\textrm{diag}(0.7,0.98,0.99)$, which is not far from the identity matrix, my equality does not hold.

So I would like to ask: *what is the correct "reflection formula" for ${}_2\!F_1$ in the matrix case ?*

Comment: *(and I have checked that this formula is true)*: finally no. The Wikipedia formula does not hold for $z$ close to $0$. Now I'm suspecting that this relation actually is not an equality, but only an equivalence when $T \sim I$.

Comment: *"The Wikipedia formula does not hold for z close to 0"*: finally yes, it holds, *but only under certain conditions on $a$, $b$, $c$*. The conditions given in Slater's book are $\Re(c) < 1$ and $\Re(c-a-b)>0$. But I've found that it still holds sometimes when these conditions are not fulfilled.

Comment: See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.05248.pdf) for an answer.